# Trackpad lagging on Lenovo IdeaPad 5 15IIIL05 with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, touchpad, lenovo, synaptics

My laptop is a Lenovo IdeaPad 5 15IIIL05. The touchpad is just lagging a lot and getting worse and worse.

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN901C:00 04F3:2A88                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:01 06CB:7F28 Mouse               id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:01 06CB:7F28 Touchpad            id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

What could be the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You do not need to fill your question with details that are more or less unhelpful to explain the problem.  You've stated your problem.  And you've provided an answer.  The extra details are not necessary, and don't add to the question.  Please stop rolling back edits to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the package `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` was the fix. It will not work immediately; you have to restart first. It does however interfere with the Gnome Tweaks function “disable touchpad while typing”. HOWEVER you can create a keyboard shortcut on there to disable it and enable it manually when you’re typing, which is what I did.

Some package info:

```
Version: 1.9.1-1ubuntu3
Priority: optional
Section: universe/x11
Provides: xorg-driver-input, xorg-driver-synaptics
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15), libevdev2 (>= 1.3), libx11-6, libxi6 (>= 2:1.2.0), libxtst6, xorg-input-abi-24, xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.18.99.901)
Suggests: gpointing-device-settings, touchfreeze
Conflicts: xorg-driver-synaptics
Breaks: kde-config-touchpad (<< 0.8.1-2~)
Replaces: xorg-driver-synaptics
Description: Synaptics TouchPad driver for X.Org server
```